# Exporting and importing Files in Parse.com

Tags: parse-platform

We have a prod and dev environment in Parse.

In the Dev environment, several class contains files, like HTML and MP3.
When we export the data from DEV, and then we import them in the prod environment, the URL of these files are changed on Parse.

Something from :

http://files.parse.com/00224919-1f70-41cb-b5f6-59ba635dbe7d/66ac16e2-43f5-4104-8e62-912eb03e914b-exercise_unlocked.svg

To

http://files.parse.com/77c04809-d42e-42fe-91ca-6b5be9297322/66ac16e2-43f5-4104-8e62-912eb03e914b-exercise_unlocked.svg

Each time you click on one of these files, you get an ACCESS_DENIED error.

This would means that we will have to import all the files anew in the Prod environment.

Is this a bug? It wasn't the case a while ago when we did our last import.

Answer (score 0):

As per parse support, you can not import/export binary data or hosted files. You need to download individual files and then upload them to the another application manually.

https://www.parse.com/questions/exporting-file-objects-and-importing-to-another-application